# Home Page Template - Specific Category

Tags: categories, page-template, conditional-content

I cannot find a specific solution to my situation. I'm sure this is an easy one though. I have my homepage set to display posts. How can I narrow the posts to a single category? I've looked elsewhere without much luck figuring it out as the homepage is using post_formats.

Thank you!

Comment: The [`pre_get_posts` codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Examples) has an example that does exactly that.

Comment: Hey Milo. I took a look at codex and have already tried variations prior to asking. Specifically, because of my theme, how can I achieve this? Note that I did not include the html code that wraps the posts. How can I apply this condition to the code in my custom page template? Excluding the footer, what I posted is all the php in the template. And thank you.

Comment: @Jarmerson , Did you try `pre_get_posts` as @Milo suggested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a page template that is not set to `Blog Posts Page`:

Using `pre_get_posts` to show only one category doesn't work as the main query contains only page content and is not a post loop. So we can do this using a secondary query using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Look at [`WP_Query` category parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters)

```
<?php

$args = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => "YOUR CATEGORY ID" ) );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

If the page is set to `Posts Page` then we can use `pre_get_posts` (in `functions.php`)

```
function home_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '1' ); // set req. cat id
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'home_category' );
```

**Note:**

As @PieterGoosen pointed:

Single pages do not need the while loop, it just need a call to the_post(). It is all you actually need. It is however always better to include the while loop part as some plugins hook into `have_posts()`

Comment: It is set to blog.

Comment: Is there no way to take the short few lines I have and make it conditional?

Comment: @Jarmerson , Is it a page template or just a page that is set to blog posts page?

Comment: Home page template. The code in my question is exactly all it is.

Comment: It does. Home Page template. It's home-page.php

Comment: `home-page.php` doesn't mean anything unless it doesn't have `Template Header` but `home.php` is special  .. Anyway if it is a template and is set to show `Blog Posts` then you can use `pre_get_posts`

Comment: the_post(); post_class(array('post')); the_content();  That's it. Nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42356/discussion-between-bravokeyl-and-jarmerson).

Comment: I will pick up tomorrow. I'm not at the computer. Thank you. Talk soon

Comment: Single pages do not need the `while` loop, it just need a call to `the_post()`. It is all you actually need. It is however always better to include the `while` loop part as some plugins hook into `have_posts()` ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen , got it

Comment: Given the configuration of my homepage, i.e. show posts, I was able to use the second snippet! It works perfectly. Thank you!!!